# Не записывать в массив полученные подряд одинаковые элементы

Tags: javascript

Есть массив - в который я получаю данные от пользователя (клавиши на которые он нажимал в калькуляторе на странице). И в историю операций калькулятора может вывестись такая запись: 1++++++++++++1=2 . Как можно Реализовать функцию(либо, что-то еще), которая будет запрещать записывать в массив одинаковые символы? Ниже код где я отлавливаю события клика на клавиши +- и тд.

```
if (target.classList.contains('operator')) {
    if (calculator.expressionData.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    handleOperator(target.value);
    updateDisplay();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ну прежде чем заносить в историю проверяйте, если символ в списке запрещённых к дублированию и если  последний символ истории  тот же, что вводят - то не вносить

Comment: Можно подробнее про список запрещенных к дублированию?

Comment: создайте список (массив) из символов `['+', '-', '/', '*']` и смотрите в нём. Вам же только их нельзя дублировать? Или какие-то ещё? Типа точки запятой...........Или  как вариант вместо этого смотреть, что символ не число

Comment: Хорошо, написать проверку на не число, но тогда все знаки не будут записываться, а не только второй, третий и тд. (Я еще совсем зеленый в программировании, сори если туплю)

Comment: нет......надо ещё проверять на то, что последний символ не был такой же как пытаются ввести

Comment: `if (target.classList.contains('operator')) {
        if (calculator.expressionData.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (calculator.expressionData.length - 1 == NaN) {
            return;
        }
        handleOperator(target.value);
        updateDisplay();
        return;
    }`